# Codeigniter Where clause not working with alias variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get results with SQL having the join of multiple tables.
but the where clause is not working...

```
$this->db->where('a.panel_id', 'r.id');
```

If I print the query it prints as

```
AND `a`.`panel_id` = 'r.id'
```

I need to have the query string escaped, like:

```
AND `a`.`panel_id` = `r`.`id`
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: where condition is not needed for join. you can use join like this $this->db->join('second_table as r','a.panel_id=r.id')

Comment: `where` shouldn't be used for how a `join` is related.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for a [join](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join) clause looks like:

```
$this->db->join('table2 r', 'a.panel_id = r.id');
$query = $this->db->get('table1 a');
```

Anyway, in order to achieve your query string with escaped identifiers, use the CI function [escape_identifiers()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=escape_id#CI_DB_driver::escape_identifiers) and set the [escape parameter in the where clause](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::where) to false:

```
$c1=$this->db->escape_identifiers('a.panel_id');
$c2=$this->db->escape_identifiers('r.id');
$this->db->where($c1, $c2, false);
```

output:

```
`a`.`panel_id` = `r`.`id`
```

Comment: You may accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to that answer if it helped to resolve your problem. You also may 

upvote it, depending on how helpful it was for you. This is the Stackoverflow way of saying **Thank You**. On the other hand, if the posted answer is 

not what you were looking for, you could add more details to your original post (OP) using the edit button just below your question or even downvote 

the answer.

Comment: @Numan See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if unfamiliar